Find the probability that $A$ wins the game.
Given that in each round of the game, the probability that $A$ wins is $\frac{1}{4}$, the probability that $B$ wins is $\frac{1}{2}$, hence the probability that they tie is $\frac{1}{4}$. Now a game consists of multiple rounds. $A$ wins if they win one round before $B$ wins two rounds. Find the probability that $A$ wins the game.
I know that for $A$ to win, several possible scenarios exist. For example, $A$ wins the first round, or there are many rounds of ties before $A$ wins for once (e.g. $TTTTA$), or $B$ wins once before $A$ does, including ties (e.g. $TTBA$). I can find the total probability that there are infinitely many rounds of tie before $A$ wins using the sum of geometric series. However, I don't know how to calculate the sum of the scenario where $B$ wins once before $A$ does as $B$'s winning can be in any order before $A$.
I'm not sure if I'm overcomplicating this problem, would appreciate any hint.

If you play the game in the same way but phrase it as, "If it is a tie, they redo the round" you can eliminate all the rounds that end in a tie and the game becomes much easier.

You can assume, without loss of generality, that no game ends in a tie.  That is, all ties may be ignored.
So, the relative probability of A winning a specific round is $~1/3,~$ and the relative probability of B winning a specific round is $~2/3.~$
Since ties are being ignored, it will take at most $~2~$ rounds for a winner to be declared.  In these $~2~$ rounds, the only way that A can lose is if B won both rounds.
Therefore, the probability of A winning is
$$1 -  \left[ ~\frac{2}{3} ~\right]^2.$$

$\underline{\text{Addendum}}$
I feel that it is a worthwhile exercise to demonstrate that the same answer is achieved if a non-elegant approach is taken.
A's probability of winning is
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n),$$
where $~f(n)~$ represents the probability that both of the following events occur.

A's first win is on round $~n.$

In the first $~(n-1)~$ rounds, B had at most, 1 win.


So:

$f(1) = \dfrac{1}{4}.$

$f(2) = \dfrac{3}{4} \times \dfrac{1}{4}.$

For $~n \geq 3:~$ 
$f(n) = \dfrac{1}{4} \times $ 
$\displaystyle \left\{ ~\left[ ~(1/4)^{(n-1)} ~\right] + \left[ ~\binom{n-1}{1} \times \frac{1}{2} \times (1/4)^{(n-2)} ~\right] ~\right\}.$


So, A's probability of winning equals
$$\frac{1}{4} + \frac{3}{16} 
+ \sum_{n=3}^\infty \left\{ ~\left( ~\frac{1}{4} ~\right)^n +  
\left[ ~\left( ~\frac{1}{4} ~\right)^{(n-1)} \times \frac{n-1}{2} ~\right]
   ~\right\}. \tag1 $$
In order to evaluate the expression in (1) above, you need two preliminary results, that both apply when $~|x| < 1.$

$\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n = \frac{1}{1-x}.$

$\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^n = \frac{x}{(1-x)^2}.$


The expression in (1) above may now be re-expressed as
$$\frac{7}{16} 
+ \sum_{n=3}^\infty \left\langle ~\left( ~\frac{1}{4} ~\right)^{(n-3)} \times   
\left\{ ~\frac{1}{64} +\left[ ~\frac{1}{16} \left( ~\frac{n-3}{2} + 1 ~\right) ~\right]
 ~\right\} ~\right\rangle $$
$$= \frac{7}{16} 
+ \sum_{n=3}^\infty \left\{ ~\left( ~\frac{1}{4} ~\right)^{(n-3)} \times   
\left[ ~\frac{5}{64} + \frac{n-3}{32} 
 ~\right] ~\right\} $$
$$= \frac{7}{16} 
+ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left\{ ~\left( ~\frac{1}{4} ~\right)^n \times   
\left[ ~\frac{5}{64} + \frac{n}{32} 
 ~\right] ~\right\} $$
$$= \frac{7}{16} 
+ \left( ~\frac{5}{64} \times \frac{1}{1 - (1/4)} ~\right)
+ \left( ~\frac{1}{32} \times \frac{1/4}{[ ~1 - (1/4) ~]^2} ~\right)$$
$$= \frac{7}{16} 
+ \left( ~\frac{5}{64} \times \frac{1}{3/4} ~\right)
+ \left( ~\frac{1}{32} \times \frac{1/4}{9/16} ~\right)$$
$$= \frac{1}{32} \times \left[ ~14 + \frac{10}{3} + \frac{4}{9} ~\right]$$
$$= \frac{1}{32} \times \left[ ~14 + \frac{34}{9} ~\right]$$
$$= \frac{1}{32} \times \left[ ~\frac{126 + 34}{9} ~\right] = \frac{1}{32} \times \frac{160}{9} = \frac{5}{9}.$$

Hint: {A does not win the game} = {B wins two rounds before A wins one round} = {The first two rounds that are not ties are won by B}.

$B$ can win two rounds in any order such as $BTB$, so I don't think it's equal to {The first two rounds that are not tied are won by $B$}

If B wins by BTB, it is still the case that the first two rounds that are not tied are won by B. The first two rounds that are not tied are rounds 1 and 3 in the outcome BTB, and both of those rounds were won by B.

@serendipity0217 Compare the first part of my answer with my Addendum.

@user2661923 I think your inelegant approach is way too much. If someone were to tell me that simply assuming each round to be a decisive (non-tie) result is not sufficiently rigorous, I would not take the approach you did and instead write the probability that B wins as an infinite sum which is easy to calculate to be 4/9. This would be way faster while still being rigorous.

@baxterbotox What alternative infinite sum did you have in mind?

@user2661923 Let $p$ be the probability that $B$ wins the game. If $B$ wins the game in $n+1$ rounds, then the $(n+1)$th round must have been won by $B$, and the first $n$ rounds must consist of $n-1$ ties and $1$ win for $B$ (which can be any of the first $n$ rounds). Then for all $n \in {1,2,...}$, the probability that $B$ wins the game in $n+1$ rounds is $nP(B)P(T)^{n-1} P(B) = n(1/2)(1/4)^{n-1}(1/2) = n(1/4)^n$. Then $p = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n (1/4)^n = 4/9$. Thus the probability that $A$ wins the game is $1-4/9 = 5/9$.

@baxterbotox Yes, this is an improvement on my infinite sum.

As baxterbotox has surmised, it is easier to compute probability of $B$ winning, with the boundary condition that $A$ doesn't win.
Let the ultimate probability that $B$ wins be $p$, and the stage where $B$ has won only $1$ game be $b$
Then we get the equations
$p = (1/4)p + (1/2)b \tag 1$
$b = (1/2)\times1 + (1/4)b \tag 2$
Solving, we get $p = 4/9$
and by the complement, $P(A\; wins) = 5/9$
